# Is it not possible for an overloaded operator= returning void be a copy assignmnent operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Referring to the page at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator, copy assignment operators, as automatically generated when needed and possible by the compiler, returns an lvalue reference of the type of itself.

So when I define an overloaded operator as below,

```
void operator=(T& t)
```

Is there still a chance that the compiler will implicitly define a default copy assignment operator?

Comment: The return type is not considered part of the the function signature so i would expect not

Comment: Why would you make the return void?  If you do you can't do things like `foo a = b = c = d = some_val;`

Comment: @NathanOliver: And that would be a bad thing?

Comment: Is there a specific problem that you are trying to solve? This question looks like a possible X/Y problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Well if he wants to prohibit it then no.  I tend to be on the side of the argument that if you provide an operator it should behave like that operator for built in types.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, but the fact that assignment chains are allowed for scalars is ludicrous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a copy-assignment operator, as specified by the language standard, in C++11 [class.copy]/17:

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.

The return type doesn't affect whether it's considered to be a copy-assignment operator. It only affects what you can do with the result of an assignment expression.

Comment: So, no (title) ​and yes (body).

Answer (score 1):

[C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator) (As you found out yourself) declares that:

> If no user-defined copy assignment operators are provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare one as an inline public member of the class.

and

> A copy assignment operator of class T is a non-template non-static member function with the name operator= that takes exactly one parameter of type T, T&, const T&, volatile T&, or const volatile T&

So in other words: as soon as you declare your own copy assignment operator (which takes a T& parameter), the compiler won't add an implicit one.

There's still the question why to return void however... (C++ coding guidelines propose to return a reference to self)

Comment: So it depends on whether the user-defined `void operator=(T& t)` qualifies as a copy assignment operator or as a non-copy assignment operator, but you don't answer which of those it is. (Your link does answer that too, so you could just include a bit more of it in your answer.)

Comment: @hvd updated answer accordingly... thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I don't see how you can come to the conclusion you have from those two quotes (though I'm not saying the conclusion is wrong). The first one, in particular, does not say anything about what will cause the compiler to *not* generate an implicit assignment operator. It only provides a condition which will guarantee that it *will* generate one. And it doesn't say whether or not there are other conditions which might also satisfy.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The specification states that compiler declares an implicit operator IF the condition matches. Which means that the compiler must check THAT the condition matches and ONLY THEN declare an implicit operator.

Comment: @Daniel It states "if", not "if and only if". "If" I win a million bucks, the sun will still go up tomorrow. But if you see the sun go up tomorrow, you can't conclude that I've won a million bucks. :) So Benjamin Lindley's right that technically, it doesn't answer it. The "only if" is implied by the lack of any other description of when copy assignment operators get generated, but it's hard to quote the lack of such a description in your answer.

Comment: if (a == 2) { do something } --> do you agree that the compiler also could execute that code if a is 3 (after all you didn't explicitly forbid it. You only said it must do it if it's 2). Or in other words: Check the official C++ specification. There you find lots of "if <condition> then compilers will <action>". You never find "if and only if <condition> ...". If you think this is not clear enough, please take it up to the specification committee.